# ¿Cómo funcionan las liberías externas de JS?

Tags: javascript, http, librería

Estoy teniendo un problema con un servicio de geolocalización y visualización de mapas. La cuestión es que algunos de estos servicios no me funcionan y sé que es porque al hacer peticiones HTTP a una URL, no obtengo la respuesta (probablemente por el proxy o el firewall).

No obstante, la aplicación usa el mismo servicio de diferentes maneras: Por peticiones HTTP para obtener un token (licencia de uso) y librerías JS embebidas en el software para luego visualizar y utilizar el servicio de mapas.

Las librerías de JS me funcionan sin problema y cargan perfectamente pero al intentar hacer la petición HTTP me falla. Es aquí donde me surge la duda.. ¿Cómo funcionan las librerías externas de JS? ¿Son peticiones que se hacen a un servidor externo? ¿Se carga el JS en el propio navegador al cargar la página?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si ver los errores o el código es complicado ayudarte. Las librerías JS que uses no son mágicas, es código como el que tú puedas escribir. Es posible que la petición esté siendo bloqueada por usar el protocolo HTTP en lugar de HTTPS. Piensa que HTTP está cayendo en desuso por ser inseguro y todos los navegadores están obligando a los desarrolladores a no usarlo

Comment: @PabloLozano la petición HTTP me falla seguramente por el Proxy o el Firewall y se hace desde un Java. Lo único que me gustaría saber cómo funcionan las librerías externas de JS para entender un poco mejor porque una librería JS se carga sin problema y una petición HTTP o HTTPS falla. El servidor y la aplicación son las mismas. Mi duda no es tanto saber por qué falla la petición sino entender el funcionamiento de la slibrerías JS.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ... habrás notado que para incluir un `.js` externo hay que indicar un elemento `<script src="XXX">...</script>`. Y esas XXX son una URL. No se que mas hay que explicar ahí O_o